# Fail to launch java web start in java 7 update 25

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I try to deploy my java web start application as [deploy java web start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

But when i launch my application, but I got exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot find cached resource for URL: http://nguyennguyen1647:8080/myweb/byte-viewer-1.0.0.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.getCachedResourceFilePath(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getCachedResourceFilePath(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.getSignedJNLPBits(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.getSignedJNLPFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDescHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I think my problem is my jar file is self-signed. 
Please tell me how to sign jar file with certificate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the self signed isn't a problem, but different signing can be

Comment: I don't understand, Please explain your idea?

Comment: *"Fail to launch java web start in java 7 update 25"* DYM it works in 1.7.0_24 (or any other version of Java)?  As a general tip:  Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: my application is OK when i run in java 7 update 17 or java 6.

Comment: ..& What was the result of the JaNeLA check?

Comment: There have some warning, But I think it's not a problem.

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-pattern-valid: Value '1024M' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[0-9]+[km]?' for type 'memorySizeType'.
cvc-attribute.3: The value '1024M' of attribute 'max-heap-size' on element 'j2se' is not valid with respect to its type, 'memorySizeType'.
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8

Comment: Try this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053890/java-web-start-cannot-find-cached-resource-for-url/17053891#17053891][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053890/java-web-start-cannot-find-cached-resource-for-url/17053891#17053891

Comment: @Paolo It's OK. But I want to cache my application. So I can't disable cache file.

Comment: I want to launch my application in offline mode.